# MSbuild takes longer than expected

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a small project with a lot of dependencies. I changed one of the files in the project and noticed that MSBuild re-compiles all the dependencies also. What might cause this? Is this the default behavior and if so how do I change it?

If it matters I'm compiling via the command line (not from visual studio)

Comment: MSBuild does not compile anything on it's own - it's a tool. Please provide more details about your actions - how are you building the project, what parameters etc.

Comment: Enable MSBuild logging and it tells all.

Answer (score 0):

It could be building them all, or it could just be checking the dependencies to determine if they need a rebuild.

First, what kinds of projects are in the solution?  More obscure project types may have targets that were not written with incremental builds in mind and may have buggy behavior (such as 2012 SQL Projects always rebuilding because it attempts to resolve SQLVAR params to file locations).

Here's some advice to get you on your way:

**Prefer a file logger allowing you to troubleshoot without relying on the console buffer.**

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /fl3 /flp3:warningsonly;logfile=msbuild.wrn /fl4 /flp4:errorsOnly;logfile=msbuild.err /fl5 /flp5:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild.log
```

This will generate three logs, two for warnings and errors, and a log with the greatest level of detail.  Open msbuild.log and identify the build for one of the dependencies.

Does the build log indicate targets were skipped?

```
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

or that they were rebuilt?

```
Building target "SqlBuild" completely.
```

**MsBuild can build your projects in parallel.**
Another trick to enhancing performance is to build your projects in parallel.  MsBuild is the scheduler and can build your dependencies in parallel using the magical "/m" switch!